# Stop/reverse animation on mouse off (baraja jquery plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've implemented the baraja jquery plugin for a section on a 'web app' that I need to create.

Rather than the plugin spreading the cards on the click of a button, I've opted to alter the script and spread out the cards on hover. On the face of it this works but if you hover over the cards and back off quickly before the animation is finished the cards will stay open. And then when you hover over the 'deck' they close. I've created a codepen below to show this:

http://codepen.io/moy/pen/OPyGgw

I've tried using `.stop();` but it doesn't seem to have an impact on the result. Can anyone help me with this?

Additionally I'd like the deck to be open on page load, then close after a second or 2. I tried this with `$( document ).ready()` including the baraja.fan call but that didn't trigger it - any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to add a mouseout handler to your hover function? http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: found nothing in the baraja plugin documentation ... seems like they didn't expect to get a usecase, where the closing animation gets triggered before the spreading animation is finished. .stop doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look errand - exactly the problem I've been having :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one really tickled me ;) tried several things, but - as already told - the plugin doesn't expect to get the close animation call faster, then the opening animation will run.

so finally i build you the following.
- opening the fan, right at document ready
- created a timeout for the mouseleave, to wait for the opening animation duration, before closing it - you will have a 400ms delay when mouseleave the element, but it will close, even when you've been to fast...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($("#baraja-el").length) {
        var $el = $('#baraja-el');
        baraja = $el.baraja();
    }

    //initial open
    baraja.fan({
            speed: 400,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            range: 80,
            direction: 'right',
            origin: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            center: true
        });

    $('.baraja-container').addClass('open');

    // navigation
    $('#baraja-prev').on('click', function (event) {
        baraja.previous();
        $('.baraja-container li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('z-index') === "1000") {
                $(this).addClass('visited');
            }
        });
    });

    $('#baraja-next').on('click', function (event) {
        baraja.next();
        $('.baraja-container li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).css('z-index') === "1010") {
                $(this).addClass('visited');
            }
        });
    });

    $('.baraja-container').hover(function (event) {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('open'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            baraja.fan({
            speed: 400,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            range: 80,
            direction: 'right',
            origin: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            center: true
        });
        }

    }, function (event) {
    curBarCon = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
            curBarCon.removeClass('open');
            baraja.close();
}, 400);

    });

    $('.baraja-container li').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('visited');
    });

});
```

since i fiddled in your codepen, you should have the working version here: http://codepen.io/moy/pen/OPyGgw
but... it's really no perfect solution. i'd suggest to get another plugin or rework baraja to get callback functions, which would test if the animation is currently running and dequeue them if needed.

rgrds,
E

Comment: Thanks for looking into that some more Errand! :) I can't see it working in the codepen, is it the right link?

Comment: Ah actually, as soon as I based your code into the codepen it worked so there must be another 'forked' version. Thanks a lot for this, it works great!! :)

Comment: you're welcome ;) but as i said, it's not the perfect solution, just a workaround. i'd suggest to fork the baraja plugin at github and rework the fan and stop functions, to react properly even when one of the animations is still running...